# .htaccess RewriteRule Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two websites, xyz.com and testsite.com (just for example). I've linked my domain xyz.com to testsite.com/content. My testsite.com/content features a .htaccess which features the following code meant to remove the .php extension from the URL:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works perfectly fine on the source website; however, it shoots off a 404 error in the xyz.com and references /content/content/login instead of /content/login in the testsite.com. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RewriteBase /` to the code so like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If it doesn't work like this, try adding the rewritebase under the options or at the top of the htaccess.